# How do I upload a text file using the DropBox API?

Tags: java, android, dropbox-api

I've used the dropbox api in other languages but I can't seem to figure out how to upload ***something*** when I'm uploading a textfile.

My current code is this:

```
FileMetadata metadata = null;                        
metadata = client.files().uploadBuilder("/test.txt")
         .withAutorename(true)
         .withMute(true)
         .withMode(WriteMode.OVERWRITE)
         .withClientModified(new Date())
         .uploadAndFinish(in);
```

But I don't understand where to put the actually data that I want to put in the file, and I couldn't find it in the official [dropbox java tutorial](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java#dropbox-for-java-tutorial) or anywhere else. I would also like to add that I'm new to java and I'm working in android studio.

Comment: Google for: How do I upload a text file using the DropBox API?

Comment: @greenapps I have done that already.

Comment: The `in` variable should be an InputStream for the file data you want to upload. There's a basic example under ["Try some API requests" in the readme](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java#try-some-api-requests). There's a more elaborate example [here](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java/blob/master/examples/upload-file/src/main/java/com/dropbox/core/examples/upload_file/Main.java#L53).

Comment: @Greg Yeah I eventually figured it out, thanks for your input.